# Ruby HTTP breaks when server is off

Tags: ruby

Net::HTTP gives a "undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass" if the server is down... is this a standard response that I can trust? Shouldnt it raise a Net:* exception?

Regards

Comment: What's the stack trace, and what version of Ruby?

Comment: You (or something somewhere) are trying to call a method `closed?` on an objet that is `nil`.  So we need some code and a stack trace here to help you out further.  Because without context this error is quite unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

It should return something like this:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:53:in `timeout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:93:in `timeout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:374:in `get_response'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:356:in `get'
from httpd.rb:2
```